# How to query on collection values ​and referenced documents values ​in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I don't know how correctly I formulated the question. I need to execute a query on both the values ​​of the collection and the values ​​of the referenced objects.

The original collection looks like this:

```
{
  "houses": [
    {
      "_id": "5fe72f0b4fd2c131bcc7dae0",
      "name": "John",
      "district": "Texas",
      "events": [
        {
          "_id": "5fe73e91ede45b3d2eca504c",
          "kind": "developer",
          "group": "facebook"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fe72f0b4fd2c131bcc7dadf",
      "name": "Michael",
      "district": "Texas",
      "events": [
        {
          "_id": "5fe73e91ede45b3d2eca504b",
          "kind": "advertiser",
          "group": "instagram"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fe72f0b4fd2c131bcc7dade",
      "name": "Frank",
      "district": "Washington",
      "events": [
        {
          "_id": "5fe73e91ede45b3d2eca504a",
          "kind": "developer",
          "group": "school"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When executing a query that meets the condition `district == "Texas"`, I need to get the following result:

```
{
  "houses": [
    {
      "_id": "5fe72f0b4fd2c131bcc7dae0",
      "name": "John",
      "district": "Texas",
      "events": [
        {
          "_id": "5fe73e91ede45b3d2eca504c",
          "kind": "developer",
          "group": "facebook"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fe72f0b4fd2c131bcc7dadf",
      "name": "Michael",
      "district": "Texas",
      "events": [
        {
          "_id": "5fe73e91ede45b3d2eca504b",
          "kind": "advertiser",
          "group": "instagram"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Under this condition: `kind == "developer"`, get the following result:

```
{
  "houses": [
    {
      "_id": "5fe72f0b4fd2c131bcc7dae0",
      "name": "John",
      "district": "Texas",
      "events": [
        {
          "_id": "5fe73e91ede45b3d2eca504c",
          "kind": "developer",
          "group": "facebook"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fe72f0b4fd2c131bcc7dade",
      "name": "Frank",
      "district": "Washington",
      "events": [
        {
          "_id": "5fe73e91ede45b3d2eca504a",
          "kind": "developer",
          "group": "school"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And for a query that satisfies the condition: `district == "Texas" && kind == "developer"`, get the result:

```
{
  "houses": [
    {
      "_id": "5fe72f0b4fd2c131bcc7dae0",
      "name": "John",
      "district": "Texas",
      "events": [
        {
          "_id": "5fe73e91ede45b3d2eca504c",
          "kind": "developer",
          "group": "facebook"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The query should be executed using **mongoose** inside the **express** route, and should be universal, processing a different set of request parameters:

```
router.get('/report', (req, res) => {
  let params = {}; 
  let { district, kind } = req.headers;

  if (district) params["district"] = district;
  if (kind) params["kind"] = kind;
  // Here should be the query
});
```

The `House` model refs to `Event`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const HouseSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  district: String,
  events: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Event'
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('House', HouseSchema);
```

I am learning **MongoDB** and **aggregation**, but I don’t know so deeply all its functions. Please tell me how to correctly execute such a request in the traditional way? I will be very grateful!

Comment: DBRef is a client-side construct.  It is not easy to work with on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$houses"},
{$match:{"houses.district":"Texas","houses.events":{$elemMatch:{"kind":"developer"}}}},
{$group:{
    _id:null,
    houses:{$push:"$houses"}
}},
{$project:{_id:0}}])
```